# Suppose $p_0, p_1, ...,p_m\in P(\mathbb{F})$ are such that each $p_j$ has degree $j$. Prove that $p_0,p_1,...,p_m$ is a basis for $P_m(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

The following problem is from Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*. There is [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671983/if-p-0-p-1-p-m-in-mathcalp-m-mathbbf-and-p-j-has-degree-j-p) that relates directly to the problem posed below, but it has no answers and I believe the question has an incorrect candidate proof.

**Ch. 2C, Problem 10:** Suppose $p_0, p_1, ...,p_m\in P(\mathbb{F})$ are such that each $p_j$ has degree $j$. Prove that $p_0,p_1,...,p_m$ is a basis for $P_m(\mathbb{R})$.

**Here is my attempt to prove this**

Each of $p_0, ..., p_m$ is in $P_m(\mathbb{R})$.

If we define a linear operator $\varphi$ on $P_m(\mathbb{R})$ that maps each of $1,x,x^2,...,x^m$ to $p_0,p_1,...,p_m$ then this linear operator is injective, hence surjective.

Thus, we can write any polynomial from $P_m(\mathbb{R})$ as a linear combination of $p_0,...,p_m$.

**I'd like to know if this proof is correct because I saw [another proof  (problem 10)](https://linearalgebras.com/2C.html) that is very tedious and I wanted a different proof.**

As a side note, before I wrote the proof above I was trying to write a proof of a specific case. The proof below is analogous to the one above, just in more words I think.

I'd like to show that the ordered list $B=(b_0, b_1, ..., b_m)=(1, x-5, (x-5)^2,...,(x-5)^m)$ is a basis of $P_m(\mathbb{R})$, where the latter is the vector space of polynomials with real coefficients of degree less than or equal to $m$.

**Here is my attempt to prove this**

$(p_0, p_1, ..., p_m)=(1, x, ..., x^m)$ is a basis for $P_m(\mathbb{R})$, which has dimension $m+1$.

Consider the linear operator $\varphi$ from $P_m(\mathbb{R})$ to $P_m(\mathbb{R})$ defined by

$$\varphi(p_i)=b_i,\ \ \ \ \ i=0,...,m$$

If we can show that $\varphi$ is injective, then it is automatically surjective, which means that every vector in $P_m(\mathbb{R})$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in $B$.

Thus, $B$ spans $P_m(\mathbb{R})$ and since the number of vectors in $B$ is the same as the dimension of $P_m(\mathbb{R})$, $m+1$, $B$ is a basis.

Let $p=\sum_{i=0}^m a_ip_i$ be any vector in $P_m(\mathbb{R})$.

Then,

$$\varphi(p)=\sum_{i=0}^m a_i b_i=\sum_{i=0}^m a_i(x-5)^i$$

For which polynomial $p$ is this expression equal to zero?

The only way is if all the coefficients $a_i$ are zero.

Thus, $null \varphi=\{0\}$, ie the set containing the zero function, making $\varphi$ injective and hence surjective.

Thus, for every $q\in P_m(\mathbb{R})$ there is some $p\in P_m(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$\varphi(p)=\sum_{i=0}^m a_i b_i=q$$

and so $(b_0, ..., b_m)$ spans $P_m(\mathbb{R})$ and is a basis.

**After writing the above, I noticed that the problem above is a special case of another problem:**

Comment: I guess you'd just need to verify that $\varphi$ is injective, and then indeed it would be an isomorphism. Another way to prove this is notice that $p_1-a_0p_0$ is a scalar multiple of $x^1$ (for some scalar $a_0$). Try generalizing this to obtain scalar multiples of all $x^j$ using linear combinations of the $p_i$'s.

Comment: Regarding your first attempt, it can be framed as showing that the set of polynomial form a *spanning set* for the subspace $P_m(\mathbb{R})$.  If you knew the dimension of that subspace was $m+1$, then the conclusion (that a spanning set of that size is a basis) will allow you to proceed expeditiously.  However it might be that the "tedious" proof you reference is so because it makes no prior assumption about the dimension.